# Android: How to know which app was opened

Tags: android

Is there a broadcastreceiver (or any other mechanism), where my app would be notified   when the user opens up another app.

I like to track what apps user has used in real time (that is notified instantly); UsageStatsManager can be used for similar functionality, but it wont provide that information in real time (it takes time window as a parameter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActivityManager` to get the information of currently running apps. Check the information via every minute (or five minutes, depends on you). By comparing the changes in the data， you can get the running time of every app.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runnings= activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo running: runnings){
        System.out.println(running.processName);
    }
```

Comment: Put that snippet in your cyclic query.